# How can I stop forwarding selection state to embedded tableViewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController embedded into a tableviewCell as a child view controller. If I press cell, not only the cell's label will highlighted, but the embedded tableviewController's cells get highlighted, I want to prevent it. How?

Answer (score 1):

try overriding the cell method `setHighlighted:animated:` without calling super. I remember Apple mentioned that behavior in `CollectionViewCell` in WWDC 2013 and maybe said they applied it to `TableViewCell` as well. I need to watch the lecture to remember how to opt-out of this